# How to get max birth date while grouping on course?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got this problem where I'm going to select the youngest student from each course in a student table.

```
SELECT name, lastname, MAX(fdate) as 'Youngest', course  
FROM student
GROUP BY course
```

Result: http://i.imgur.com/9mx5Mfy.png

This query returns highest date in the three courses, but the names associated are wrong.
This is just a simple task in the `MySQL` course, and we're not going to use `JOINs.`

Comment: IMO this statement is syntactically wrong. At least with other databases like Oracle you have to list all non-aggregated columns in the `group by` -> `group by name, lastname, course`

Comment: @user2989408 no. youngest is the most recent date = max date. Old people have old dates which are min dates

Comment: @hgoebl It's a special Mysql (mis)feature that you can select fields without grouping on them. Mysql will then just select a value from one of the rows in the group. This is why the name is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT s1.name, s1.lastname, s1-fdate
FROM student s1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 'YOUNGEST'
    FROM student s2
    WHERE s2.course = s1.course
    AND s2.fdate > s1.fdate
)
```

In this query, I want to retrieve, among the students on the same course (s2.course = s1.course), the youngest (s2.fdate > s1.fdate)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Though its a little bit complicated to be on the level we are at. All other tasks are as easy as `SELECT * FROM student
WHERE fdate > '1990-1-1'` and such. Just picking out small and simple things.

Answer (score 0):

if you're not going to use JOINs so you can use inner select

```
select
  A.course_name as "Name", 
  max(A.day_of_birth) as "Birth date", 
  (select 
     student_name 
   from students 
   where course_name = A.course_name and day_of_Birth=max(A.day_of_birth) limit 1
  ) as "who"
from students A
group by A.course_name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79a19/13/0

Comment: this is not efficient.. if the table is large at all it will be a really slow query to execute

Comment: I thing, execution plan is selecting courses where is max(birth_date) than execute subselect. May be I'm wrong

Comment: when you do a sub select with a where condition like that it does a select for every select in the outside select... meaning that you are doing a select to compare results for every row in your (outside select table) students table... for the purposes of this question this is probably a fine solution, but in general that kind of method is a bad idea